# How can users download the SQLite database of the application in the Dotnet core?

Tags: sqlite, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I used an SQLite database in my MVC project. I wanna the users can be able to download this database. This is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used an SQLite database in my MVC project. I wanna the users can be
> able to download this database. This is possible?

You can download it. please check the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly BloggingContext context; 
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, BloggingContext bloggingContext, IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        context = bloggingContext;
        _logger = logger;
        _hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Download()
    {
        //get file path
        var path = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "WebApplication.db");

        //read the file in the stream 
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
        }
        memory.Position = 0;
        //return the file.
        return File(memory, "application/octet-stream", "WebApplication.db");
    }
```

In the View page, use a button to call the download method to download the database file.

Reference:

[Upload/ Download Files In ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-download-files-in-asp-net-core-2-0/)

[Upload/Download Files in ASP.NET Core 2.0](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1203408/upload-download-files-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score -1):

You can use several methods. For example work with SQLite using one of the packages from the NuGet repository, or use the Entity Framework Core, which abstracts from the DB structure and allows you to work with data as objects of programming language standard classes.